# Missing dependency 'protobuf' when building Gazebo from source

Tags: installation, dependencies, gazebo-7

The problem arises with the Protobuf dependency. Its latest version is installed. Error code:

````
colcon build --merge-install
Starting >>> gz-cmake3
Finished <<< gz-cmake3 [0.80s]                      
Starting >>> gz-utils2
Starting >>> gz-tools2
Finished <<< gz-tools2 [0.56s]                                                              
Finished <<< gz-utils2 [0.87s]                      
Starting >>> gz-math7
Finished <<< gz-math7 [2.37s]                      
Starting >>> gz-common5
Starting >>> gz-msgs9
Starting >>> sdformat13
--- stderr: gz-msgs9                                                                                             
CMake Error at /root/workspace/install/share/cmake/gz-cmake3/cmake3/GzConfigureBuild.cmake:72 (message):
  -- BUILD ERRORS: These must be resolved before compiling.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:109 (gz_configure_build)


CMake Error at /root/workspace/install/share/cmake/gz-cmake3/cmake3/GzConfigureBuild.cmake:74 (message):
  --    Missing dependency [Protobuf] (Components: all)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:109 (gz_configure_build)


CMake Error at /root/workspace/install/share/cmake/gz-cmake3/cmake3/GzConfigureBuild.cmake:76 (message):
  -- END BUILD ERRORS

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:109 (gz_configure_build)


CMake Error at /root/workspace/install/share/cmake/gz-cmake3/cmake3/GzConfigureBuild.cmake:81 (message):
  Errors encountered in build.  Please see BUILD ERRORS above.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:109 (gz_configure_build)


---
Failed   <<< gz-msgs9 [0.54s, exited with code 1]
Aborted  <<< gz-common5 [0.85s]                                                                     
Aborted  <<< sdformat13 [21min 36s]                                           
                                        
Summary: 4 packages finished [21min 45s]
  1 package failed: gz-msgs9
  2 packages aborted: gz-common5 sdformat13
  3 packages had stderr output: gz-common5 gz-msgs9 sdformat13
  9 packages not processed
```
````

Comment: Are you following [these install instructions](https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/install_ubuntu_src)? On Ubuntu? Which version?

Comment: Yes. I following these install instructions for Ubuntu. But I have Debian 12.

Answer (score 1):

> `--    Missing dependency [Protobuf] (Components: all)`

In above line, it says that it does not find `Protobuf`.

Below are the 'protobuf' Ubuntu packages I have installed. Given you are on Debian, I would first look into installing corresponding packages, if they are not already installed:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep -i protobuf

libprotobuf-dev/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 3.12.4-1ubuntu7.22.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libprotobuf-lite23/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 3.12.4-1ubuntu7.22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libprotobuf23/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 3.12.4-1ubuntu7.22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
protobuf-compiler/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 3.12.4-1ubuntu7.22.04.1 amd64 [installed]
python3-protobuf/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 3.12.4-1ubuntu7.22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

If this does not help, I suggest to have a look at the CMake script that searches the Protobuf package, and see what exactly it is looking for.

According to the `CMakeLists.txt` file of the `gz-msgs` package, line 85, a custom script `src/gz-cmake/cmake/FindGzProtobuf.cmake` is used:

```
#--------------------------------------
# Find Protobuf
gz_find_package(GzProtobuf
                 REQUIRED
                 COMPONENTS all
                 PRETTY Protobuf)
```

The way I would do this is to try to add some debug output to that file, e.g. remove `QUIET` in the following line and see if it outputs relevant info or not:

```
find_package(Protobuf ${GzProtobuf_FIND_VERSION} QUIET CONFIG)
```

This also seems a relevant issue to read through:
https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-cmake/issues/9

Comment: Thank you but now I have new problem `

CMake Error at /home/administrator/workspace3/install/share/cmake/gz-cmake3/cmake3/GzConfigureBuild.cmake:74 (message):
  --    Missing dependency [curl]
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:78 (gz_configure_build)


CMake Error at /home/administrator/workspace3/install/share/cmake/gz-cmake3/cmake3/GzConfigureBuild.cmake:74 (message):
  --    Missing dependency [YAML]
CMake Error at /home/administrator/workspace3/install/share/cmake/gz-cmake3/cmake3/GzConfigureBuild.cmake:74 (message):
  --    Missing dependency [ZIP]'

Comment: Debian is not a supported OS for ROS, so you either have to resolve all missing dependencies, or you have to change to a supported OS.